# Does the Legendre-Fenchel transform/convex conjugate of strongly convex functions have any desirable properties?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, operator-theory, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

It is well known in convex analysis that when a closed, proper, function $f$ is Legendre-type, that is, essentially strictly convex and essentially smooth, the Legendre transform yields a dual function $g$ which has the same properties, whereby the gradient is a bijection from the domain of $f$ to the domain of $g$.

Does there exist a similar set of results for strongly convex $f$? or for essentially strongly convex $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, strong convexity is conjugate to uniform smoothness or Lipschitz-continuous differentiability (where the Lipschitz constant is the reciprocal of the modulus of strong continuity), see, e.g.,

*Azé, Dominique; Penot, Jean-Paul*, [**Uniformly convex and uniformly smooth convex functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.5802/afst.809), Ann. Fac. Sci. Toulouse, VI. Sér., Math. 4, No. 4, 705-730 (1995). [ZBL0870.49010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0870.49010).

Comment: Does the gradient remain a bijection? If not, what guarantees it?

Comment: Yes, strongly convex functions are in particular strictly convex, which is the property that guarantees the bijection (of the subgradient as a set-valued operator, which reduces to the gradient if you also have smoothness).